# Why does this optimization algorithm in R stop after a few function evaluations?

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization

I have a code which has been used for some paper.
After defining the function to be optimized, the author used the Nelder-Mead method to estimate the parameters needed. When I run the code, it freezes after 493 function evaluations have been used, it doesn't show any kind of error message or anything. I've been trying to find some info but I haven't been lucky. How can I modify the `optim` command in order to evaluate all possible combinations, and/or what is preventing the function from being optimized?

Here's the code. It's relatively long, BUT the second-to-last line (`system.time(stcopfit...)`) is the ONLY ONE I need to make work / fix / modify. So you can just copy&paste the code (as I said, taken from the author of the mentioned paper) and let it run, you don't have to go through the all code, just the last few lines. This is the [data](http://www.filedropper.com/untitled_53) over which to run the optimization, i.e. a matrix of [0,1] uniform variables of dimension 2172x9.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here's a screenshot in RStudio (it took around 2 minutes to arrive at 493, and then it's been stuck like this for the last 30 minutes):

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
#download older version of "sn" package
url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sn/sn_1.0-0.tar.gz"
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="source")
install.packages(signal)
library(sn)
library(signal)

#1. redefine qst function 
qst <- function (p, xi = 0, omega = 1, alpha = 0, nu = Inf, tol = 1e-08) 
{
  if (length(alpha) > 1) 
    stop("'alpha' must be a single value")
  if (length(nu) > 1) 
    stop("'nu' must be a single value")
  if (nu <= 0) 
    stop("nu must be non-negative")
  if (nu == Inf) 
    return(qsn(p, xi, omega, alpha))
  if (nu == 1) 
    return(qsc(p, xi, omega, alpha))
  if (alpha == Inf) 
    return(xi + omega * sqrt(qf(p, 1, nu)))
  if (alpha == -Inf) 
    return(xi - omega * sqrt(qf(1 - p, 1, nu)))
  na <- is.na(p) | (p < 0) | (p > 1)
  abs.alpha <- abs(alpha)
  if (alpha < 0) 
    p <- (1 - p)
  zero <- (p == 0)
  one <- (p == 1)
  x <- xa <- xb <- xc <- fa <- fb <- fc <- rep(NA, length(p))
  nc <- rep(TRUE, length(p))
  nc[(na | zero | one)] <- FALSE
  fc[!nc] <- 0
  xa[nc] <- qt(p[nc], nu)
  xb[nc] <- sqrt(qf(p[nc], 1, nu))
  fa[nc] <- pst(xa[nc], 0, 1, abs.alpha, nu) - p[nc]
  fb[nc] <- pst(xb[nc], 0, 1, abs.alpha, nu) - p[nc]
  regula.falsi <- FALSE
  while (sum(nc) > 0) {
    xc[nc] <- if (regula.falsi) 
      xb[nc] - fb[nc] * (xb[nc] - xa[nc])/(fb[nc] - fa[nc])
    else (xb[nc] + xa[nc])/2
    fc[nc] <- pst(xc[nc], 0, 1, abs.alpha, nu) - p[nc]
    pos <- (fc[nc] > 0)
    xa[nc][!pos] <- xc[nc][!pos]
    fa[nc][!pos] <- fc[nc][!pos]
    xb[nc][pos] <- xc[nc][pos]
    fb[nc][pos] <- fc[nc][pos]
    x[nc] <- xc[nc]
    nc[(abs(fc) < tol)] <- FALSE
    regula.falsi <- !regula.falsi
  }
  x <- replace(x, zero, -Inf)
  x <- replace(x, one, Inf)
  Sign <- function(x) sign(x)+ as.numeric(x==0)
  q <- as.numeric(xi + omega * Sign(alpha)* x)
  names(q) <- names(p)
  return(q)
}

#2. initial parameter setting
mkParam <- function(Omega, delta, nu){
  ndim <- length(delta)+1;
  R <- diag(ndim);
  for (i in 2:ndim){
    R[i,1] <- R[1,i] <- delta[i-1];
    if (i>=3){for (j in 2:(i-1)){R[i,j] <- R[j,i] <- Omega[i-1,j-1];}}
  }
  LTR <- t(chol(R));
  Mtheta <- matrix(0, nrow=ndim, ncol=ndim);
  for (i in 2:ndim){
    Mtheta[i,1] <- acos(LTR[i,1]);
    cumsin <- sin(Mtheta[i,1]);
    if (i >=3){for (j in 2:(i-1)){
      Mtheta[i,j] <- acos(LTR[i,j]/cumsin);
      cumsin <- cumsin*sin(Mtheta[i,j]);}
    }
  }
  c(Mtheta[lower.tri(Mtheta)], log(nu-2));
}

#3. from internal to original parameters
paramToExtCorr <- function(param){
  ntheta <- dim*(dim+1)/2;
  theta <- param[1:ntheta];
  ndim <- (1+sqrt(1+8*length(theta)))/2;
  LTR <- diag(ndim);
  for (i in 2:ndim){
    LTR[i,1] <- cos(theta[i-1]);
    cumsin <- sin(theta[i-1]);
    if (i >=3){for (j in 2:(i-1)){
      k <- i+ndim*(j-1)-j*(j+1)/2;
      LTR[i,j] <-  cumsin*cos(theta[k]);
      cumsin <- cumsin*sin(theta[k]);}
    }
    LTR[i,i] <- cumsin;
  }
  R <- LTR %*% t(LTR);
  R;
}

#4. show estimated parameters and log likelihood
resultVec <- function(fit){
  R <- paramToExtCorr(fit$par);
  logLik <- -fit$value;
  Omega <- R[-1, -1];
  delta <- R[1, -1];
  ntheta <- dim*(dim+1)/2;
  nu <- exp(fit$par[ntheta+1])+2;
  c(Omega[lower.tri(Omega)], delta, nu, logLik);
}

#5. negative log likelihood for multivariate skew-t copula
stcopn11 <- function(param){
  N <- nrow(udat);
  mpoints <- 150;
  npar <- length(param);
  nu <- exp(param[npar])+2;
  R <- paramToExtCorr(param);
  Omega <- R[-1, -1];
  delta <- R[1, -1];
  zeta <- delta/sqrt(1-delta*delta);
  iOmega <- solve(Omega);
  alpha <- iOmega %*% delta / sqrt(1-(t(delta) %*% iOmega %*% delta)[1,1]);
  ix <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=dim);
  lm <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=dim);
  for (j in 1:dim){
    minx <- qst(min(udat[,j]), alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu);
    maxx <- qst(max(udat[,j]), alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu);
    xx <- seq(minx, maxx, length=mpoints);
    px <- sort(pst(xx, alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu));
    ix[,j] <- pchip(px, xx, udat[,j]);
    lm[,j] <- dst(ix[,j], alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu, log=TRUE);
  }
  lc <- dmst(ix, Omega=Omega, alpha=alpha, nu=nu, log=TRUE);
  -sum(lc)+sum(lm)
}

#6. sample setting
dim <- 9;
smdelta <- c(-0.36,-0.33,-0.48,-0.36,-0.33,-0.48,-0.36,-0.33,-0.48);
smdf <- 5;
smOmega <- cor(udat);
smzeta <- smdelta/sqrt(1-smdelta*smdelta);
iOmega <- solve(smOmega);
smalpha <- iOmega %*% smdelta /sqrt(1-(t(smdelta) %*% iOmega %*% smdelta)[1,1]);

#7. estimation
iniPar <- mkParam(diag(dim),numeric(dim),6);
system.time(stcopfit<-optim(iniPar,stcopn11,control=list(reltol=1e-8,trace=6)));
resultVec(stcopfit);
```

Comment: just to clarify. By "freezes" you mean that `optim()` stops printing tracing information, but you don't get back to the R prompt? Can you show the last few lines of trace output? (Does the workload monitor on your OS show that R is still using CPU time?)  Since you specified `maxit=100`, and each Nelder-Mead iteration should take on the order of 4 or 5 function evaluations, that's about where I'd expect the optimization to stop.  I hate to say it, but a screenshot might be helpful ...

Comment: Sorry for the "maxit=100", I forgot to remove it before posting. You're correct: basically it takes around 2 minutes to evaluate 493 functions, then it stops printing tracing info and I can't get back to the R prompt. I've added the screenshot.

Comment: hmmm.  If you had set `hessian=TRUE` I could understand this, but as it is I'm stumped.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for your inputs. Slightly unrelated question: is there a way to reach the maximum allowed number of iterations for Nelder-Mead method? Default for Nelder-Mead is 500, using `maxit` I can set it to 1000 or whatever number. Is there a way to let it run "indefinitely" until the function is optimized?

Comment: You could try setting `maxit` to some ridiculously large number (say `1e10`,  or if it's handled as an explicit integer somewhere you could try 2147483647 (the maximum positive integer).  `(2/493*.Machine$integer.max)/(60*24*365)` is about 16.6, so that should provide for 16 years' worth of computation with your current setup before the optimizer gives up ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you arrive at by step 493 lead to an infinite loop in your `qst` function: not having any idea what this very complex code is actually doing, I'm afraid I can't diagnose further.  Here's what I did to get that far:

- I stated `cur.params <- NULL` in the global environment, then put `cur.params <<- params` within `stcopn11`; this saves the current set of parameters to the global environment, so that when you break out of the `optim()` call manually (via Control-C or ESC depending on your platform) you can inspect the current set of parameters, and restart from them easily
- I put in old-school debugging statements (e.g. `cat("entering stcopn11\n")` and `cat("leaving stcopn11\n")` at the beginning and at the next-to-last line of the objective function, a few within `stopc11` to indicate progress markers within)
- once I had the "bad" parameters I used `debug(stcopn11)` and `stcopn11(cur.param)` to step through the function
- I discovered that it was hanging on dimension 3 (`j==3` in the `for` loop within `stcopn11`) and particularly on the first `qst()` call
- I added a `maxit=1e5` argument to `qst`; initialized `it <- 1` before the `while` loop; set `it <- it+1` each time through the loop; changed the stopping criterion to `while (sum(nc) > 0 && it<maxit)`; and added `if (it==maxit) stop("hit max number of iterations in qst")` right after the loop

1e5 iterations in `qst` took 74 seconds; I have no idea whether it might stop eventually, but didn't want to wait to find out.

This was my modified version of `stcopn11`:

```
cur.param <- NULL  ## set parameter placeholder

##5. negative log likelihood for multivariate skew-t copula
stcopn11 <- function(param,debug=FALSE) {
    cat("stcopn11\n")
    cur.param <<- param ## record current params outside function
    N <- nrow(udat)
    mpoints <- 150
    npar <- length(param)
    nu <- exp(param[npar])+2
    R <- paramToExtCorr(param)
    Omega <- R[-1, -1]
    delta <- R[1, -1]
    zeta <- delta/sqrt(1-delta*delta)
    cat("... solving iOmega")
    iOmega <- solve(Omega)
    alpha <- iOmega %*% delta / 
          sqrt(1-(t(delta) %*% iOmega %*% delta)[1,1])
    ix <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=dim)
    lm <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=dim)
    cat("... entering dim loop\n")
    for (j in 1:dim){
        if (debug) cat(j,"\n")
        minx <- qst(min(udat[,j]), alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu)
        maxx <- qst(max(udat[,j]), alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu)
        xx <- seq(minx, maxx, length=mpoints)
        px <- sort(pst(xx, alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu))
        ix[,j] <- pchip(px, xx, udat[,j])
        lm[,j] <- dst(ix[,j], alpha=zeta[j], nu=nu, log=TRUE)
    }
    lc <- dmst(ix, Omega=Omega, alpha=alpha, nu=nu, log=TRUE)
    cat("leaving stcopn11\n")
    -sum(lc)+sum(lm)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time. Sorry to bother you again but my R expertise is limited to built-in functions, it's the first time I encounter such a code and really need this to work for a project. Two questions: 1) could you maybe post your modified code, for example by editing my code and adding yours? Somehow it didn't work for me (after it reached 493 again I got out of optim() manually and cur.params was still null, so I guess I did something wrong); 2) what do you mean when you say qst took 74 seconds?

Comment: (2) I mean that I ran `qst` manually with the specified parameters and used `system.time()`. It took 74 seconds to run 1e5 iterations, which was as many as I allowed it.